# Evaluating $\int_{\Bbb R^n\setminus B_1} \frac1{\left(|z|-\frac12\right)^{2(n+1-2a)}} dz$ and $\int_{B_{1/2}(u)} \frac1{|u-v|^{n+2a-2}} dv$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

> Let $n\in\mathbb{N}, n\ge 2$ and let $0<a<1$. I am trying to compute explicitly the integrals given by:
>
> $$\int_{\mathbb R^n\setminus B_1} \frac{1}{\left(|z|-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2(n+1-2a)}} dz\quad\text{ and }\quad \int_{B_{1/2}(u)} \frac{1}{|u-v|^{n+2a-2}} dv$$
>
> Here, $B_1$ denotes the unit ball centered at $0$ and $B_{1/2}(u)$ the ball of radius $1/2$ centered at $u$.

The 2 integrals come from a cliff of computations (which I checked and I am pretty confident that is correct), but I do not know how to compute them.

For the first one, maybe one can do that:
$$\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb R^N\setminus B_1} \frac{1}{\left(|z|-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2(n+1-2a)}} dz &= \int_1^{+\infty}\int_{\partial B_1} \frac{1}{\left(|\rho|-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2(n+1-2a)}} d\square \rho^{n-1} d\rho \\[4pt]
&= n\omega_n \int_1^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\left(|\rho|-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2(n+1-2a)}} \rho^{n-1} d\rho
\end{align}$$
but I do not know how to proceed.

Concerning the second one, I feel like saying that it should converge since $a<1$, but I do not know ho to compute it.

Could someone help with both the integrals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the modulus signs in the integral; just substitute $t=\rho-\frac{1}{2}$, use the Binomial expansion on the numerator and integrate term-by-term. So: $$\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\left(\rho-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2(n+1-2a)}} \rho^{n-1} d\rho =\int_\frac{1}{2}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{t^{2(n+1-2a)}} (t+\tfrac{1}{2})^{n-1} dt$$
$$= \sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2^{n-1-r}} {n-1 \choose r}\int_\frac{1}{2}^{+\infty} t^{-(2n+2-4a-r)}dt$$
$$= -\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} {n-1 \choose r} \frac{2^{(n+2-4a)}}{(2n+1-4a-r)} .$$
In the second integral, substitute $w=v-u$ and use spherical polars again - as the domain of integration becomes a ball round the origin.

Are these hints enough or do you want more detail?

Comment: mcd, thank you for your comment. If I understand correctly, the second integral should be equal to $|S^{N-1}|\int_0^{1/2} \rho^{1-2a} d\rho = |S^{N-1}| \frac{\rho^{2-2a}}{2-2a}\big|_0^{1/2}$, right? Could you please instead give more details concerning the first one? Thank you.

Comment: mcd, I am interested in how to use binomial expansion in the first integral. Could you please provide more detail?

Comment: mcd, thank you for the details. Do you think that my computation for the second integral is correct? Thanks.

Comment: Yes I do. And substituting the limits would make it neater: $$\dfrac{S^{n-1}}{(1-a)2^{3-2a}}.$$